# Can't create Exchange Credentials on Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, exchange-server

I have to connect to inbox of an exchange server mail and reach the attachments in mails. I have this part of my code and having no problem while debugging in console application. I created a windows service to check mailbox and get attachments periodically. However, windows service cannot create credentials throws an exception. Please check this program and share your ideas with me. What can be the difference between while I'm debugging and running on windows service.

```
private FindItemsResults<Item> ConnectToInbox()
    {
        ExchangeService _service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
        _service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password");

        _service.AutodiscoverUrl("mail@mail.com");
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = _service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(1000));
        Logger.Write("There is/are " + (findResults.Items.Count) + " email(s) in Inbox");
        return findResults;
    }
```

Comment: Services running as "Local Service" don't have network access. What privileges is your service running with?

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek oh I didn't know that. I will try to run service with different account.